# How do I display a simple text box in objective-c/cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, popup

I would like to display a box containing text to the user while the code continues to run and then close the box at a later time. Something like NSRunAlertPanel that you could open and then close later.

Pseudo-code:

```
OpenTextBox *box = OpenTextBox("Please wait.")

various commands

[box close]
```

Comment: How do you want to present it? In an existing window or view? As a separate window?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're asking the wrong question.  If you want to show UI that just says "Please wait", the typical Mac OS X way to do it is with a progress indicator.  See ["Progress Indicators"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgIndic/ProgIndic.html) and/or the NSProgressIndicator reference -- it can display both the bar that fills with blue and the gear that spins around.

If you think you really do need to show a modal dialog, look at ["Sheet Programming Topics"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/).